# Using an Array to verify login and password

Tags: php, arrays

I can get an array of the user file when I access the DB.  What am I missing is how to use that array to verify the input from the user.  The array also contains another piece of data that I need to capture and use on a later page?

Here is the code that generates the array and part of a foreach I was trying to get to work.  Am I on the right track?

```
$sql = "SELECT * from users;";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $dbc); //run the query
if ($result)
{
    $html .= '<h2>Result Found </h2>'.PHP_EOL; 

    //Grab arrays from the result
    for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++)
    {
        $array = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        print_r($array);
        foreach ('username' as $inputUsername){

        echo 'password';

    }

    }
}
else
{
    $html .= '<h2>Error: '.mysql_error().' </h2>';
}
```

Comment: You should not use mysql_* functions any more, they are deprecated and will be removed. When changing to PDO or Mysqli you should read up on parameterized queries, which will sort out your sql injection vulnerabilities. Then you should query for a user with the data that has been submitted. Something like: 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', and execute it with a binded parameter $_POST['email']. Then you should verify their password, which is done differently depending on how you save password hashes (don't use md5/sha), and you're good to go :)

Comment: For a simple login script this is wrong, you're pulling all users from the database then iterating in php, what if you have 1,000,000 users ? see the problem ? I'll post an answer in a bit on how to do it correctly/better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, instead of fetching all the users in your database then iterating over one by one to check for passwords, you can tell MySQL to "give me the password of the user who has a username of exampleuser" like this:

```
$username = "exampleuser";
$sql = "SELECT `password` from users where `username` = '$username';";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $dbc); //run the query
if ($result)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $password = $row['password'];
    echo '<h2>Result Found '.$password.'</h2>'.PHP_EOL;
}
else
{
    echo '<h2>No user found, or Error: '.mysql_error().' </h2>';
}
```

On a side note pleace notice that mysql_ functions are deprecated, i left them in there to keep your code intact and show you the minor differences.

Comment: I see your point and I tried to implement the changes and get this error.    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\validation.php on line 88  Thanks for the help.  I am new to PHP

Comment: Cleared the one error then now I have Undefined index and Undefined variable for username.  Again I am new to PHP.  I appreciate all the help.  Here us what I have

Comment: Sorry my bad, there's a missing semicolon after `$username = "exampleuser"`, it should be `$username = "exampleuser";`

Comment: No problems tom, again that's my mistake, i misspelled $username :), if you rename the first one to $username it'll work !

Comment: $dbc = dbConnect();
$usrename = ($_POST['username']);
$html = "";
$sql = "SELECT 'password' from users where 'username' = '$username';";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $dbc); //run the query
if ($result)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $password = $row['password'];
    $html .= '<h2>Result Found '.$password.'</h2>'.PHP_EOL;
}
else
{
    $html .= '<h2>No user found, or Error: '.mysql_error().' </h2>';
}

Comment: I went back to the post you had just before mine and made the changes.  Now I get a blank page.  I enter in the username and password and hit submit and it thinks and thinks then presents a blank page with the address of the page that has the validation code

Comment: That means it worked, you simply didn't echo the contents of $html, i changed the code again now, use this final version and it'll work !

Comment: YEAH!!!! it says result found.  There is another piece of data that is associated with the user a company name.  How can I capture that and use it to direct the user to a specific page? and if they fail the login redirect them back to the login.  Is it as simple as in html?

Comment: Yes it's pretty simple, but I suggest to keep it simple is to either take this to a chatroom then post it in another question, since those are different things, do you want to do that ?

Comment: Yes Please.  I've never used the chat here.  Also your suggesting posting a new question?  Correct

Comment: I was going to take this to chat but apparently you need at least 20 rep to be able to chat, so simply just post a new question somewhere and post the link here so I can find it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212402/using-login-data-to-direct-user-traffic

Comment: Here is the the title of the post " Using login data to direct user traffic "

Answer (score 0):

You will want to change to PDO or mysqli usage ASAP (mysql will become deprecated). In addition, there is no need to use `SELECT * from users` when you can use `SELECT * from users WHERE username = $username;`. It reduces the workload when you have many records.

Answer (score 0):

I created this code in my application. Hope this will help.

```
    <?php
    $username = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/','',$_POST['username']);
    $password = base64_encode($_POST['password']);

    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbc); // setup database connection

    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from users where `username` = '$username'");
    $num = $sql->num_rows;
    if ($num) {
        // User found
        $row = $sql->fetch_assoc();
        if($password != $row['password']) {
            echo "Wrong password";
        }
        else {
            // user data in array
            print_r($row);
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "User not found";
    }
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

`preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/','',$_POST['username'])` -> to prevent unnecessary input

`base64_encode($_POST['password']);` I always use encryption for this input.

Comment: I gave it try and got a handful of errors.  It looks like the bulk of them are from the fact that the inputs are getting picked up and the connection to the DB is not activating.  But it will still echo the whole array

Comment: you should define mysqli($dbc);

$dbc = "localhost, dbusername, dbpassword, dbname";