# Using login data to direct user traffic

Tags: php

I need some help with a redirect please.  I have the piece of code and would like to redirect the user to a specific page.  The table that contains the username and password also contain a third piece of data, an org name.  Each org will have its own page. --I added the name of a company in line 17 but I keep getting the echo at the bottom.  Any help would be great.

```
$dbc = dbConnect();

$username = "exampleuser";
$sql = "SELECT 'password' from users where 'username' = '$username';";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $dbc); //run the query
    if ($result)
{
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $password = $row['password'];
         //   echo '<h2>Result Found '.$password.'</h2>'.PHP_EOL;
        $myPassword = $_POST['password'];
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        //$password = $row['password'];
        //match passwords
            if($myPassword == $password){
                //Decide where to send user depending on company column:
                $privilege = $row['company'];
                if($privilege == "companyname"){
                    header( 'Location: admin1.php' );
                }
                if($privilege == "user"){
                    header( 'Location: user.php' );
                }
                if($privilege == "other"){
                    header( 'Location: other.php' );
                }
        exit; //This tells php to stop executing as soon as we redirect
    }else{
        echo "Wrong username/password, try again";
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the name of the extra field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically any redirects in php are done using the `header` function

for example, a call like this:

```
header( 'Location: http://google.com' );
```

will redirect the user to google.com

Knowing this piece of info we'll use that to redirect the user depending on the information you fetch from the database,

let's say we have the user's password in from a POST variable called `myPassword`

```
$myPassword = $_POST['password'];
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $password = $row['password'];
    //match passwords
    if($myPassword == $password){
        //Decide where to send user depending on privilege column:
        $privilege = $row['privilege'];
        if($privilege == "admin"){
            header( 'Location: admin.php' );
        }
        if($privilege == "user"){
            header( 'Location: user.php' );
        }
        if($privilege == "other"){
            header( 'Location: other.php' );
        }
        exit; //This tells php to stop executing as soon as we redirect
    }else{
        echo "Wrong username/password, try again";
    }
}
else
{
    echo '<h2>No user found, or Error: '.mysql_error().' </h2>';
}
```

Comment: OOOHHHk I think I see it.  I was hoping to be able to send the Admin ti the Admin page and the users to the same page and have different content displayed from a folder on the server based on the org name.  That way if a new org is added this section would not need to be edited.

Comment: I see, so let's say your domain is exmpale.com, what directories do you want to redirect to ? and what content do you want to show users ?

Comment: I tried the script that you posted and got the variable error again here is my login code:

Comment: ok says its too long.  heres the hart of it:<label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>';
print'    <div class="controls">';
print'         <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">';
print'    </div>';
print'  </div>';
print'  <div class="control-group">';
print'    <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>';
print'    <div class="controls">';
print'      <input type="text" name="password id="password" placeholder="Password">';
print'    </div>';
print'  </div>';

Comment: I added it to the original question all of it.  I feel like I am double naming it

Comment: For example user from xyz.org logins in to example.com.  They then would get directed to user.php.  The frame work will be the same for all orgs.  The content will come from a folder on the server with pictures and other marketing type material.

Comment: I just noticed I was missing a " and added it.  Now I am getting Notice: Undefined variable: and Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given :they both reference the same line----Again thanks for taking the time to help me understand this

Comment: ok I started combining the two pieces and I get the "RESULTS FOUND" but then there is no redirect, I get the "WRONG USERNAME/PASSWORD" displayed

Comment: That's because you're not fetching the extra field from the user, you need to change your query to be:
`"SELECT \`password\`, \`company\` from users where 'username' = '$username'";
`

Comment: I tried that : "SELECT `password` , `company` from `users` where `username` = '$username'";  and still don't get taken to the other page.  I can't thank you enough for your help

Comment: And does it make sense to do something lik: $_SESSION [$company]; ?  That way I can have a function on the user page that is something like-- function userContent($company)

Comment: No probs., can you echo the contents of `$row['privilege']` ?this will sow us what's going on !, and yes you can use $_SESSION to store data into the users' sessions, just remember to call `session_start()` at the very beginning of your script before <html> or any other outputs, that's because it must be called before the http headers are sent.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, just got off work.  I tried to echo $row['privilege'] and $row['company'] and got a blank page.

Comment: No problems, `$row['privilege']` should be empty, but `$row['company']` shouldn't, can you add your SQL schema for the users table to your question ? it will clear things up !

Comment: $sql = "SELECT 'password' , 'company' from 'users' where 'username' = '$username'";

Comment: I have tries backticks as well.

Comment: Any additional advice?

Comment: No I wasn't talking about your query, i'm talking about the user table schema